# I need to sign every week on a diagram in my Power BI report

Tags: charts, powerbi, visualization

I've created a bar chart where I have values on axis Y and weeks on axis X. I want to sign every week on this chart. The problem is that I have weeks with no data and I still want to show this blank weeks. But I can't make it to start from first week,it automatically start from first not blank week.I tried to play with continuous and categorical type of data on axis X but it didn't help. I've already chosen option "show elements without data". But it still doesn't look like a want.
For best understanding I'll show you what I have and desired result.

Now it looks
[**this way**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMXk.png) [and **this way**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyV3E.png)

But **I want** that it look
[**this way**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXWec.png)

Thank you for any useful tips.

Comment: Make a table with all week numbers (this can be a calendar table - normally you have one), make a relation between the field from this new table and week number field from your data, and show the field from the new table in the axis.

Comment: [Andrey Nikolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8649393/andrey-nikolov)
Thank you so much for help, it works.